# How to calculate the center of a drawing (multiple rectangles)

Tags: c#, paint, picturebox

I have a C# windows form where Im painting multiple rectangles:

[image]

Im doing that inside the `OnPaint` event of my `picturebox`.

> Is there any "easy" way to get the center of that drawing?

This is my code:

```
private void pbBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            Rectangle leftInsertionBox = new Rectangle(_leftPadding, _topPadding + _boxBase, _insertion, _boxFront);

            Rectangle leftCoverBox = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width, _topPadding + _boxBase, _boxBase, _boxFront);

            Rectangle leftTopDustBox = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width - (_insertion + _boxBase) / 2, _topPadding, (_insertion + _boxBase) / 2, _boxBase);
            Rectangle rightTopDustBox = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width + _boxHeight, _topPadding, (_insertion + _boxBase) / 2, _boxBase);

            Rectangle topRect = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width, _topPadding, _boxHeight, _boxBase);
            Rectangle frontRect = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width, _topPadding + _boxBase, _boxHeight, _boxFront);

            Rectangle leftBottomDustBox = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width - (_insertion + _boxBase) / 2, _topPadding + topRect.Height + frontRect.Height, (_insertion + _boxBase) / 2, _boxBase);
            Rectangle rightBottomDustBox = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width + _boxHeight, _topPadding + topRect.Height + frontRect.Height, (_insertion + _boxBase) / 2, _boxBase);

            Rectangle bottomRect = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width, _topPadding + _boxBase + _boxFront, _boxHeight, _boxBase);
            Rectangle backRect = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width, _topPadding + _boxBase + _boxFront + _boxBase, _boxHeight, _boxFront);

            Rectangle rightCoverBox = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width + _boxHeight, _topPadding + _boxBase + _boxFront + _boxBase, _boxBase, _boxFront);

            Rectangle rightInsertionBox = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width + _boxHeight + rightCoverBox.Width, _topPadding + topRect.Height + frontRect.Height + bottomRect.Height , _insertion, _boxFront);

            Rectangle bottomGlueBox = new Rectangle(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width, _topPadding + topRect.Height + frontRect.Height + bottomRect.Height + backRect.Height, _boxHeight, _glue);

            // solid brush
            SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);

            LinearGradientBrush linearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(topRect, Color.Red, Color.Yellow, 90);

            ColorBlend cblend = new ColorBlend(3);
            cblend.Colors = new Color[3]  { Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green };
            cblend.Positions = new float[3] { 0f, 0.5f, 1f };

            linearGradientBrush.InterpolationColors = cblend;


            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 1))
            {
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                DoRotation(e);

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, leftInsertionBox);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, leftCoverBox);

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, leftTopDustBox);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rightTopDustBox);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, leftBottomDustBox);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rightBottomDustBox);

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, topRect);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, topRect.X+1,topRect.Y+1,topRect.Width-1,topRect.Height-1);

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, frontRect);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, frontRect.X + 1, frontRect.Y + 1, frontRect.Width - 1, frontRect.Height - 1);

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, bottomRect);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, bottomRect.X + 1, bottomRect.Y + 1, bottomRect.Width - 1, bottomRect.Height - 1);

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, backRect);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, backRect.X + 1, backRect.Y + 1, backRect.Width - 1, backRect.Height - 1);


                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rightCoverBox);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rightInsertionBox);

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, bottomGlueBox);
            }


        }
```

Comment: Is the drawing the large box? Or is it the form? Do you always draw the same shapes?

Comment: Adding them to a GraphicsPath and using its Bounds rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
  // init left point
            List<Point> boundariesCoords = new List<Point>();
            boundariesCoords.Add(new Point(_leftPadding, _topPadding));


 // final right point
            boundariesCoords.Add(new Point(_leftPadding + leftInsertionBox.Width + leftCoverBox.Width + bottomGlueBox.Width, _topPadding + topRect.Height + frontRect.Height + bottomRect.Height + backRect.Height + bottomGlueBox.Height));


     int totalX = 0, totalY = 0;
                foreach (Point p in boundariesCoords)
                {
                    totalX += p.X;
                    totalY += p.Y;
                }
                int centerX = totalX / boundariesCoords.Count;
                int centerY = totalY / boundariesCoords.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

getting the center of the bounds should be trivial (width/2, height/2) + (offsetX, offsetY) so I assume that's not what you're referring to. To take a "center of mass" of all of the rectangles you are drawing, just track the outermost edges, loosely:

```
for each rectangle
    minLeft = min(currentLeft, minLeft)
    maxRight = max(currentRight, maxRight)
    minTop = ...
    maxBottom = ...

centerX = (maxRight - minLeft) / 2 + minLeft
centerY = ...
```

does this help answer your question?